# Changing useragent in request headers for HTML5/FLASH HLS player?

Tags: user-agent, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I have a site where I host live streams, and now our programmers restricted m3u8 files to be played only with specific user-agent otherwise it return 403 error.
We tried using GrindPlayer, but their support told us they do not support custom user agent.
Do you guys know any HLS HTML5 or FLASH player which support useragent to be set while requesting m3u8 file.

We are forced to use VLC webapp, and Chrome users can't watch videos.
This is major issue to us.

**EDIT:**

I just figured out this code

```
<video width="352" height="198" controls>
    <source src="playlist.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
</video>
```

Works great in Android, Egde, IE etc, but not in Chrome.
Why Google Chrome makes everything so difficult?

Comment: or at least send NO user agent, because it works that way

Comment: I know flash restrics us to do so. But i'm not sure with html5.
It is really tough which advice to give.

Comment: How does using the <video> tag for HLS work in IE? I thought it only ever worked in Edge and Safari, and on Android.